# Can't figure out where HTML and JavaScript based contact form is sending its data

Tags: javascript, html, var, contact-form

So I took this code for a personal website from GitHub, but I cannot figure out how the contact form works. With the current code, on pressing the submit button, the page just refreshes. How can I make it send an email to me? The other stuff seems to be working fine, like the submit button is disabled until the text fields are filled etc. It's just that when I submit its unclear where the form data is going

HTML:

```
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-input" placeholder="Full name" required data-form-input>

          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Email address" required data-form-input>
        </div>

        <textarea name="message" class="form-input" placeholder="Your Message" required data-form-input></textarea>

        <button class="form-btn" type="submit" disabled data-form-btn >
          <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
          <span>Send Message</span>
        </button>

      </form>
```

Form.js:

```
    // Fetching HTML Elements in Variables by ID.
var x = document.getElementById("form_sample");
var createform = document.createElement('form'); // Create New Element Form
createform.setAttribute("action", ""); // Setting Action Attribute on Form
createform.setAttribute("method", "post"); // Setting Method Attribute on Form
x.appendChild(createform);

var heading = document.createElement('h2'); // Heading of Form
heading.innerHTML = "Contact Form ";
createform.appendChild(heading);

var line = document.createElement('hr'); // Giving Horizontal Row After Heading
createform.appendChild(line);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
createform.appendChild(linebreak);

var namelabel = document.createElement('label'); // Create Label for Name Field
namelabel.innerHTML = "Your Name : "; // Set Field Labels
createform.appendChild(namelabel);

var inputelement = document.createElement('input'); // Create Input Field for Name
inputelement.setAttribute("type", "text");
inputelement.setAttribute("name", "dname");
createform.appendChild(inputelement);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
createform.appendChild(linebreak);

var emaillabel = document.createElement('label'); // Create Label for E-mail Field
emaillabel.innerHTML = "Your Email : ";
createform.appendChild(emaillabel);

var emailelement = document.createElement('input'); // Create Input Field for E-mail
emailelement.setAttribute("type", "text");
emailelement.setAttribute("name", "demail");
createform.appendChild(emailelement);

var emailbreak = document.createElement('br');
createform.appendChild(emailbreak);

var messagelabel = document.createElement('label'); // Append Textarea
messagelabel.innerHTML = "Your Message : ";
createform.appendChild(messagelabel);

var texareaelement = document.createElement('textarea');
texareaelement.setAttribute("name", "dmessage");
createform.appendChild(texareaelement);

var messagebreak = document.createElement('br');
createform.appendChild(messagebreak);

var submitelement = document.createElement('input'); // Append Submit Button
submitelement.setAttribute("type", "submit");
submitelement.setAttribute("name", "dsubmit");
submitelement.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
createform.appendChild(submitelement);
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? "on pressing the submit button, the page just refreshes" - what else did you expect? I don't see any code that blocks the usual form submission

Answer (score 1):

The code has this quite-unnecessary statement:

```
createform.setAttribute("action", "");
```

A `form` element with no `action` attribute / a blank `action` attribute sends its data to its own URL (the URL of the page the form appears on) unless overridden by the a `formaction` attribute on the submit button used to submit the form. From [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-action):

> The `action` and `formaction` content attributes, if specified, must have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.
>
> The action of an element is the value of the element's `formaction` attribute, if the element is a submit button and has such an attribute, or the value of its form owner's `action` attribute, if it has one, or else the empty string.

The code you've shown doesn't set any `formaction`, and explicitly sets `action` to a blank string, so the form get submitted to the URL of the page it's on. That's why when you press Submit, the page is refreshing.

The MDN page for the [`action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) attribute on `form` doesn't mention this explicitly, but the [first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#examples) on the page does:

> ```html
> <!-- Form which will send a GET request to the current URL -->
> <form method="get">
>   <label>Name:
>     <input name="submitted-name" autocomplete="name" />
>   </label>
>   <button>Save</button>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: @Kaiido - I would call it out. Good that the example later on does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your response. So should I add a formaction attribute to the submit button of my code? Or do I need to redo the whole form?

Comment: @MNBlol - It depends on what you're doing. If you have just one submit button, or you want all of them to submit to the same place, put an `action` attribute on the `form`. If you want each button to control the destination, put `formaction` attributes on them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have just one submit button which I want to use to send the form data to me email. So should I make a new form from scratch? or is this form.js usable?

Comment: @MNBlol - Just change the value in the line I quoted in the answer to the URL you want to submit to.